# What does this "N" icon represent (not NFC)

Tags: notification-icons

[image: N icon]

I haven't been able to find it in any icon lists, and the NFC icon drowns out other search results.

Galaxy S6, Android 5.1.1

Comment: Where does it show up in your S6? Give us the full screenshot.

Comment: @Firelordi just figured it out by checking my notifications area. Probably should have done that first, but I'm new to this android thing and still figuring it out. Anyway at least there's a Google-able answer available :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured out that it is the icon for "Netflix"